# Dynamic Grouping in R | Grouping based on condition on applied function

Tags: r, aggregate

**In R, in aggregate() function, How to specify stopping condition on grouping on applied function on the variable?**

For example, I have data-frame like this: "df"
[Input Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBEoQ.jpg)

**Note**:  Assuming each row in input data frame is denoting single ball played by a player in that match. So, by counting a number of rows can tell us the number of balls required.

And, I want my data frame like this one: [Output data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0DBj.jpg)
My need is: How many balls are required to score 10 runs?

Currently, I am using this R code:
`group_data <- aggregate(df$score, by=list(Category=df$player,df$match), FUN=sum,na.rm = TRUE)`

Using this code, I can not stop grouping as I want, it stops when it groups all rows. I don't want all rows to consider.

**But How to put constraint like "Stop grouping as soon as score >= 10"**
By putting this constraint, my sole purpose is to count the number of rows satisfying this condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome at the R-side of SO. Please always add the example data as data.frame R code to your question to make it easier for us to answer. Thx :-)

Comment: Your expected result may depend on the sorting order, what is your requirement here?

Comment: I guess using `cumsum` + filterering by all cumsum values <= 10 + counting the rows per group could work.

Comment: Thanks..My requirement is to count the number of balls taken to score 10 runs by each player in each match. Assuming each row in input data frame is denoting single ball played by a player in that match. So, by counting a number of rows can tell us the number of balls required.

Comment: If one of your reasons for stopping at that point is to to speed it up the calculation, then its a trickier problem. I think answers by @akrun and r-yoda still sum the entire data set.

Comment: I have deleted my answer due to an error, but here I want to keep the answer of @akrun (credits go to him): "Also, you could do setDT(df1)[, {i1 <- !shift(cumsum(score) > 10, fill = FALSE); .(score = sum(score[i1]), Count = sum(i1))}, .(match, player)] Or otherwise, use the .I, but then you may have to do the group by again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(match, player) %>% 
    filter(!lag(cumsum(score) > 10, default = FALSE)) %>% 
    summarise(score = sum(score), Count = n())
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   match [?]
#   match player score Count
#   <int>  <int> <dbl> <int>
#1     1     30    12     2
#2     2     31    15     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(match = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), player = c(30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L), score = c(6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6)), .Names = c("match", 
 "player", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Almost your solution worked. But If I apply to the case like "Stop grouping as soon as score >=50", still your solution sums up rows for "score<50". But thankfully my need is satisfied with easy looking code with more ease.